# How to handle the render of a large list of items in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large list of items to render and list data get updated in realtime with socket-io. How to handle performance issues? it gets updated heavily and table of items rendered so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider:

1. render cost of a large list
2. updating an item

For #1 you can try using a windowing library such as [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), this will make the burden on the DOM much lighter, instead of rendering thousands of items, you will actually be rendering only a few tens.

For #2 make sure that when an item updates, only that items updates and not the list. You can use [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to ensure your list items are only renders again when their props change.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat and solved my problem a different way, by implementing the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method in my component:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  // Note: lodash's "isEqual" method is useful for performing a deep comparison
  // of the given objects, which is more than JavaScript can do natively:
  return !_.isEqual(this.props.listItems, nextProps.listItems);
}
```

This is perhaps a better overall solution, because:

- it's easier to implement (i.e.: don't have to wrap your existing component in a `React.memo()` [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)
- it's supported even on older versions of React that don't have "memo" (i.e.: versions older than 16.6.0, which was released in 2018)